# Sentence structure: time vs place --> "I studied 6 years at the University of Graz for this"

Tags: sentence-structure

I was wondering what sounded more natural:

1. I studied at the **University of Graz 6 years** for this.
2. I studied **6 years at the University of Graz** for this.

This is the sentence that would come beforehand: *I've started teaching in an Austrian high school. I studied ...*

Comment: Both are fine, really.

Comment: Thank you! Maybe "I studied 6 years at the University of Graz for this" emphasizes the 6 years as more important information?

Comment: Whatever comes first is usually more emphasized in any language, isn't it? :)

Comment: I had heard or read somewhere that the most important info comes at the end (in English)

Comment: For me that's absolutely counterintuitive but I'd like to hear what native speakers say

Comment: I am a native speaker and writer.

Comment: Oh sorry, I mixed you up with the other person who commented in the post below. I see, well thank you! I wonder where I had heard that the last info is the most important one. I'm glad to be wrong!

Comment: I ***don't*** like #1 much. You can get away with discarding preposition ***for*** if adverbial ***6 years*** comes immediately after the verb ***studied***. But with another relatively long adverbial like ***at the University of Graz*** coming in between them I think it's stylistically weak to drop ***for***. Note that native speakers aren't in the least bothered by a second ***for*** in the "adverb of purpose" ***for this*** even if it comes immediately after the "adverb of manner" ***for 6 years***, so that's no reason to discard it.

Comment: 'I studied _X years_ at _Institution_  (or the alternative order you asked about) is often used bitterly, e.g. I studied six years at the University of Graz for this (said when employed washing dishes in a schnitzel joint.

Comment: We normally write numbers smaller than some size, typically, 11, in words, so we would write 'I studied [for] **six** years at (somewhere).

Answer (score 1):

The first sentence places the emphasis on the duration you studied (six years), while the second places more emphasis on where you studied (University of Graz).
So it really depends on what you want to get across.
But If you're not trying to highlight how long you studied in order to teach I'd go for the second construction.

(Caveat, I'm not a native speaker so read an answer from a native too)

Comment: I see no good reason to assume the "more important" adverbial element comes first. A speaker could *explicitly* emphasise *either* the location *or* the duration simply by placing heavy stress on whichever element he wanted to draw attention to, regardless of the sequence they occur in. And a writer could use italics or boldface type to achieve the same effect.

Comment: Firstly I think the element that usually gets more emphasis is the one in the **end**. And yes, the writer can always explicitly emphasize _anything_ in the sentence with italics or boldface or quotation marks, but since the author didn't *explicitly* emphasize anything, what's relevant is what is *implicitly* emphasized.

Comment: And @E.V. I've also read about how the last things are emphasized in Steven Pinker's *The Sense of Style*. I can't remember what he called it but I've found other articles calling this "backloading".

Comment: I think the idea that "backloading" significantly *automatically* places emphasis on the last item (or adverbial quality) mentioned is nonsense. Sometimes it might, other times it wouldn't. The *length, syntactic complexity*, and *vocabulary* of the elements probably make more difference in most cases. Imho it's not really something the average learner should be concerned with - it's not even as important as the fact that it's "clunky" to omit ***for** [6 years]* in #1 (probably down to *a non-native speaker's misunderstanding* concerning the acceptability of repeated instances of ***for***).

Comment: @FumbleFingers I agree that saying the last item always gets more emphasis is an oversimplification. What I meant was that, holding everything else constant (the content, vocabulary), backloaded phrases usually receive more weight. Also, as you pointed out, this isn't applicable in all cases, so I can see why it might be somewhat too advanced for an average learner.

Comment: As to the omission of "for" in the first sentence, don't you think that "I studied at the University of Graz for 6 years for this." is equally "clunky"? (a better construction might be "For this, I studied at the University of Graz for 6 years.")

Comment: I've said several times that native speakers don't normally notice the repetition of prepositions such as ***for*** - especially when the *exact* significance differs (within adverbial elements of ***purpose*** and ***duration***, for example). (And I *specifically* pointed out in my last comment that worrying about such things is characteristic of *non-native speakers*, so really you're just proving my point! :)